# Image not rendered properly in the view for the Image in flutter

Tags: image, flutter

I am getting image loaded to the `CircularProfileAvatar` by both means of camera and gallery successfully. But Image rendered on view is not in circular as shown in the screenshot. how should I make it sure that the image rendered to the child of `CircularProfileAvatar` is circular [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9oCD.png). In the image, you can see the orange portion which should not be visible instead the entire area inside the brown circle should be covered with the image either selected from the gallery or picture from the camera.

I am using building this new app in flutter.

This Dependency is used [CircularProfileAvatar](https://pub.dev/packages/circular_profile_avatar)

```
Image imagepic() {
      if (_imageFile == null) {
        return Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'));
      } else {
        return Image.file(_imageFile);
      }
    }

final profilePic = CircularProfileAvatar(
      null,
      child:
          imagepic(), //sets image path, it should be a URL string. default value is empty string, if path is empty it will display only initials
      radius: 50,);
```

Comment: Use `fit: BoxFit.cover` @Johnny Warner

Comment: CircularProfileAvatar is this your own custom widget? Please share that code as well

Comment: @jitsm555 `CircularProfileAvatar` is not my custom widget, I got it from `https://pub.dev/`

Comment: Please share dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `BoxFit.cover` which cover fill the circular area

```
 CircularProfileAvatar(
        null,
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: I tried on my end it is working, Can you share me image URL which you are trying

Comment: Let me try some more things, it might due to some other properties it is not working

Comment: I checked it, it issue with the images, when you select the portrait image it doesn't render to the whole area, but if you use square images it does cover complete area

Comment: @JohnnyWarner: Can you please accept the answer, if the solution satisfied your question